# How do I sort an alphabetical text field?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a couple of records that need to be sorted but the field is varchar.  They use the English Alphabet from A-Z. After Z it goes from AA, AB, AC, etc… for example:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(x VARCHAR(30));

INSERT #foo(x) SELECT 'A'
UNION SELECT 'AA'
UNION SELECT 'Z'
UNION SELECT 'B'
UNION SELECT 'AB'
UNION SELECT 'BB';
```

The ordering I want in the result is:

```
A
B
Z
AA
AB
BB
```

I know I SHOULD use a number field and sort by that, but at the moment I don’t have that option. I am using SQL Server and the front end is on a report in Access 2010.

Comment: I added table structure and the desired results for @Rick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might work. You can sort by length of the value which will group the single characters followed by double characters. Within those groups the values will be sorted alphabetically.

```
SELECT      Column1 
FROM        dbo.Table1 
ORDER BY    LEN(Column1)
        ,   Column1
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, I a bit confused.  It sounds like you want a funky sort order.  You want single letters first, and THEN normal sort order.  (A fully normal sort would have A, AA, AB, AC, then B)

First, simple sorting on a alphabetic field

```
 select SORTFIELD, OTHER, COLUMNS, IN-TABLE
 from  MYTABLE
 order by SORTFIELD
```

But that's not what you want. The problem is you never tell us where you want AAA.  Does it go after AA or after ZZ ?

AAA After ZZ:

```
 select SORTFIELD, OTHER, COLUMNS, IN-TABLE
 from  MYTABLE
 order by LEN(SORTFIELD), SORTFIELD
```

AAA After AA (before AB)

```
 select SORTFIELD, OTHER, COLUMNS, IN-TABLE
 from  MYTABLE
 order by case LEN(SORTFIELD) when 1 then 0 else 1 end , SORTFIELD
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Declare @SomeStuff table (val varchar(10));

Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('a');
Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('b');
Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('c');
Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('az');
Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('ab');
Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('zz');
Insert @SomeStuff (val) Values ('abc1');


Select * From @SomeStuff order by LEN(val), val
```

Uses SQL Server but should still work.

Results:

```
val
---
a
b
c
ab
az
zz
abc1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for you

```
Select *
from MyTable
Order By foo ASC, foo2 ASC, foo3 ASC
```

Using the Order by column ASC will allow you to order that column alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

I use a function `len` to count all characters in the field and order alphabetically with this function

```sql
(
     ORDER BY  
     case when @orderArmario = 0 AND @orderLocal = 0 then '' end ,
     case when @orderArmario = 1 then LEN(e.Armario) end asc,
     case when @orderArmario = 1 then e.Armario end asc,
     case when @orderArmario = 2 then LEN(e.Armario) end desc,
     case when @orderArmario = 2 then e.Armario end desc,
     case when @orderLocal = 1 then LEN(e.local) end asc,
     case when @orderLocal = 1 then e.local end asc,
     case when @orderLocal = 2 then LEN(e.local) end desc,
     case when @orderLocal = 2 then e.local end desc
)
```